# IOS: why devicetoken was not created, when the user does not allow for remote notifications

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, devicetoken

I'm created an application which is use remote notification service,
and also prepare a web service to collect devicetoken and some device data. 
working flawlessly, there is no problem.

but, I realized something weird. (maybe it's not so weird when consider about working principles of remote notification service)

when user install application on device very first time, 
and during first run, an alert dialogs appear, and ask user's acceptance for remote notifications.

I think, devicetoken is not created if user does not allow remote notifications, 
and as a result, `didregisterforremotenotificationwithdevicetoken` method is never called after that.

but, if user allows notifications during first running of application, `devicetoken` is created.
and `didregisterforremotenotificationwithdevicetoken` method call when users run the application, 
even user switch off all remote notifications later in notification center.

so, in first scenario, 
if user does not allow remote notification at the begining, 
how can I call `didregisterforremotenotificationwithdevicetoken` without devicetoken?

Answer (score 0):

If the user does not allow it, you will never get a device token (this is why the user is asked in first place). You cannot send a notification either..

Instead you can react to `application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:`

Also be aware that the device token may be regenerated from time to time.

You can read more about it at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW2

Comment: but, I think "didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError" will not working to, if user does not allow remote notifications.